# Haskell Aeson JSON, filter out illegal characters

Tags: json, parsing, haskell, instance, aeson

Using Haskell with the Aeson JSON Hackage, and given the following JSON:

```
{
    "base": "GBP",
    "date": "2017-10-27",
    "rates": {
        "#USD": 1.3093,
        "#EUR": 1.1282
    }
}
```

What is the beste way to implement a `FromJson` instance?

Currently I have this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, DeriveGeneric #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson

data Conversion = Conversion {
  base :: String,
  rates  :: Rates }
  deriving (Show, Generic)

data Rates = Rates {
  eur :: Float,
  usd :: Float }
  deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON Conversion
instance FromJSON Rates where
  parseJSON (Object o) = trace ( show(o)) Rates <$> o .: "#USD" <*> o .: "#EUR"
```

I have defined both possibilities in the `instance FromJSON Rates`. I tried to do it with the more generic way, but the 'illegal' characters `#` are not allowed in the `data` part.

So in this case I have only two annoying fields. But if I want to extend this and get multiple annoying characters (#, @, - etc.), do I have to define every field? Or is there a smarter and faster way to achieve the same?

Comment: I cannot reproduce any error - I tried in ghci (+overloadedstrings) `let x :: Maybe Conversion = decode "{\"base\":\"base\",\"rates\":{\"#USD\":1,\"#EUR\":2}}"` with your instances.

Comment: if you have non-standard json - you'll have to write the `parseJSON` instance declaration yourself. If you are defining the json yourself - I would refrain from adding "strange" field accessors - like # @ and so on - and stick to the usual lower case with dash syntax.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe absolutely true. Unfortunately the Dutch weather forecast site is using the "strange" field accessors. Using the answer given by **Mateusz Kowalczyk** solves my problem, thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deal with this by using `fieldLabelModifier` and replacing the problematic fields with your own. This allows you to be selective about which names are modified which is very useful if you have large records with only a few weirdly named fields that you can't directly put in your type.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main (main) where

import           Data.Aeson
import           Data.Aeson.Types
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BSL
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M
import           GHC.Generics
import           System.Environment (getArgs)

data Conversion = Conversion
  { base :: String
  , rates  :: Rates
  } deriving (Show, Generic)

newtype USD = USD Float
newtype EUR = EUR Float

data Rates = Rates
  { eur :: Float
  , usd :: Float
  }
  deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON Conversion

instance FromJSON Rates where
  parseJSON = genericParseJSON opts
    where
      fields = M.fromList
        [("usd", "#USD"), ("eur", "#EUR")]
      opts = defaultOptions
        { fieldLabelModifier = \s -> M.findWithDefault s s fields }

main :: IO ()
main = do
  [file] <- getArgs
  decode <$> BSL.readFile file >>= \case
    Nothing -> putStrLn "Parse failed!"
    Just conversion -> print (conversion :: Conversion)
```

With this we get

```
[nix-shell:/tmp]$ ./T /tmp/rates.json
Conversion {base = "GBP", rates = Rates {eur = 1.1282, usd = 1.3093}}

[nix-shell:/tmp]$ cat /tmp/rates.json
{
  "base": "GBP",
  "date": "2017-10-27",
  "rates": {
    "#USD": 1.3093,
    "#EUR": 1.1282
  }
}
```

Just remember to use the same Aeson options if you ever define `ToJSON` instance for your type!